# Changing Javascript within an HTML document to an external Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This Javascript Function..

```
function ClearTotals() {  

    document.getElementById("total1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("total2").value = "";
}
```

sets resets the values in two form fields. However when I move this function, unchanged,  to an external Javascript and reference it in the HTML page as below:

```
<script src="http://xxxxxxx.org/pkjs/js1.js/"></script>
```

it doesn't work.

Do I need to pass some reference to the document which is used in the function, or is there some other reason why this doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error when you try to call the function? Which error?

Comment: Javascript might not find your file with the trailing '/' on your src.  I've added an answer since I couldn't get the script tag to display nicely.

Comment: Are you referencing this script from the head of the document? It is possible that the elements you reference do not exist when called.

Comment: The error, from the Console  is peter3.html:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: ClearTotals is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (peter3.html:12)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you put in an answer. Answers should be used to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is js1.js - as the error message made clear !  For some reason only the first function was being read even though I can see no problems with the structure of the file.  If I delete all the other functions, and test the function by typing the url in the browser, I see the javascript code for ClearTotals().

And when I submit the HTML form, the field values clear as they should.  That's really good -  there are no issues with putting internal js code into an external file. Thanks again to everyone for their input and apologies that the problem seems down to me !